# How do I duplicate an xcode project without red text?

Tags: xcode

I have recently duplicated my Xcode project to make a project with about 80% of the same coding but there are files on the left that are in red text. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: the targets are already duplicated

Comment: Red filenames mean the referenced file doesn't exist where the project thinks the file should be.

Comment: If its red, it may mean that your project file is associated with a file, but the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that are displayed in red are missing from the directory where the project is located. In other words, they exist in the project, but not at the expected location on disk.

The solution, since you said your projects aren't identical (80% overlap), is to simply delete the red files from the project if you don't actually need them. Alternatively, providing Xcode with a copy of missing file in the appropriate spot will change its color back to black.

Comment: Also, if you can't figure out where the "appropriate spot" is, you can  simply delete the file, then drag and drop (from Finder window) into your Xcode project (making sure to select the "copy" option to copy the file into your project's folder-- instead of just linking to said file at whatever location it is).

Comment: How do I do that? I'm still learning how to use Xcode and this is the first time that I really did something like this. Thanks